# Assignment of a value, followed by comparison in "if" statement's condition in C

Tags: c, if-statement, coding-style

I want to write some code with the following logic. From a clarity and conciseness point of view, is the first approach better than the other two?

```
if(kErrNone != (cs_error = get_last_error(component)))
{
    /* Do something. */
}


if((cs_error = get_last_error(component)) != kErrNone)
{
    /* Do something. */
}


cs_error = get_last_error(component);
if(cs_error != kErrNone)
{
    /* Do something. */
}
```

Comment: I would use the third way. An assignment in the condition of an `if` block is easily mistaken for a comparison.

Comment: The advantage of the first is if you accidently assign, the compiler will flag an l-value assignment error.  I prefer the 3rd though - fewest chances for mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of conciseness, the first two **if** blocks are clearly better than the third one.

In fact, there is no significant difference between the first **if** and the second **if** as you are simply changing the sides of the comparison expression.

The third one unnecessarily adds one more statement as the assignment of a value to **cs_error** can be smartly combined into the **if** block. But yes, there is a chance of error if you are not careful about the braces.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it's the third one. Since the condition is simpler to evaluate.